# Matrix exponential error in scipy.linalg with python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I want to use matrix exponential for rotation and boost aka Clifford algebra calculation but whenever I try to use scipy.linalg.exom method I get this error "array must not contain infs or NaNs" or "cannot convert float infinity or NaN to integer" even I don't have any infty or Nan value any of matrices. Here is a example of calculation:

First I building 4x4 matrices squares of two are I4 and other two are -I4

```
def mat_mul(n,m):
    return np.kron(n,m)
def mat_builder(n):
    I2 = np.eye(2, dtype=np.float16)
    n_2 = np.array([[0,-1],[1,0]],dtype=np.float16)
    i=2
    m = [np.kron(I2,n_2), np.kron(I2,I2), np.kron(n_2, I2), np.kron(n_2,n_2)]
    while i!=n/2: 
        comb = [(i, j) for i in m for j in m]
        m = [mat_mul(k,l) for k,l in comb]
        #for k,l in zip(m,m):
         #   m = mat_mul(k,l) 
        i = len(m)/2
    return m
    
m = mat_builder(4)
```

Then I want to apply rotation or boost as e^(w/2) x e^(-w/2) here w is angle in bivector (m x m matrix) format and x is a vector vector x.m where m are matrices and x coordinates in 4D

```
X = 1*m[0] + 1*m[1] + 1*m[2] + 1*m[3]
W =  2*np.pi*np.matmul(m[1],m[3]) # + np.pi*m[1] + np.pi*m[2] + np.pi*m[3]
np.matmul(np.matmul(linalg.expm(W/2),X),linalg.expm(-W/2))
```

I wanted make rotation of 2*pi around y axis (m_13) but linalg.expm cannot calculate for angle around pi or 2*pi only small amounts
Note: here I already imported numpy as np and from scipy import linalg.

Why I am getting infinity and Nan values here? and Is there another method take matrix exponential other than scipy.linalg? Can you suggest me another program make this calculation better? in C++ I need to write matrices by hand I guess maybe Julia or R is better for this?

Thank you already for your responses!

Comment: Full error message please.  We can't just take you word that `W` does not have the forbidden values.  You have to verify that.

Comment: When I run your code (after including `from scipy import linalg`), I don't get an error.  The result of the last expression, `np.matmul(np.matmul(...))`, is a 4x4 array whose values are all slight perturbations of 1 or -1.

Comment: `linalg.expm` uses the Pade approximation, a well known method.  If I recall the correctly is has to first take a matrix inverse, which would have problems with inf/nan.